# How to retrieve individal latlng object with getGeometry()?

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I have a .geojson file. Inside the file there is one Feature and that feature has this property:

`"geometry": { "type": "LineString", "coordinates": [ [ 103.766547, 1.377559, 0.0 ], [ 103.771405, 1.374479, 0.0 ] ] }`

What I am trying to do now is something like this: when I mouse over a feature, I want to get two separate latlng objects from within the coordinates array. Using my code below:

```
 map.data.addListener("mouseover", function(event) {
    var coordinates = event.feature.getGeometry("coordinates");
    console.log(coordinates);
  });
```

Below is what is shown inside the console:

[image]

so the `coordinates` variable contains one 'i' property. 'i' is an array with two objects inside it.

Is it possible to get two separate latlng object from this array ?

I want to achieve this because I hope that later I can get the distance between these two latlng objects.

Answer (score 0):

[`LineString`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/data#Data.LineString) has a `.getArray()` method which returns the array of `LatLng` objects:

```
 map.data.addListener("mouseover", function(event) {
    var coordinates = event.feature.getGeometry("coordinates").getArray();
    for (var i=0; i<coordinates.length; i++) {
      console.log(coordinates[i].toUrlValue(6));
    }
  });
```

[proof of concept fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/4ft1z8nj/1/)